# Prismic Integration Field: Not possible to receive Shopify product metafields

Tags: shopify-api, prismic.io

I cannot fetch [Shopify product metafields](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference/objects/metafield) using Prismic Integration field via GraphQL API.

What I did:

- Created a document with Integration field https://prnt.sc/11dima8
- Tried to fetch the product data via GraphQL API, but product metafields are missed https://prnt.sc/11dinv1

What did I check:

- The metafields can be found via Shopify GraohQL https://prnt.sc/11akxvp
- Data is synced https://prnt.sc/11diq30

How can I retrieve product metafields from Shopify using Prismic Integration field? Does somebody have the same scenario? Probably some extra configurations should be done, but I'm not aware about them.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that question is relevant anymore as only Prismic team knows about this issue, here is the topic on Prismic forum: https://community.prismic.io/t/integration-field-not-possible-to-receive-shopify-product-metafields/

Answer (score 1):

Well, in fact, fetching Metadata from Shopify requires making an extra call to Shopify API that makes their API time out on the response size.

One temporary solution that we can provide for the moment is to add a link to your metadata, and you fetch them after on your side.

Having a micro-service to fetch all the data works as well, but you have to use a queue system so that if any item fails to sync due to a timeout, for example, you try several times to get it.
Also, you need to manage the authentication with Shopify API on your own.